# How to add increment to ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that has many fields, and the user can make a copy of part of the form to input more data.

It is exactly the same but like form 2, but each of the `ng-model` properties are unique and used to send the data back to an `api` I have made a directive that copies the form part and isolate scope and all that is ok.

I am stuck on how to add an increment to each `ng-model` so i'm thinking eg. `vm.add.something + increment` but how can I do this?

I have tried something like

```
 vm.counter = function () {
        var count = 1;
         count += count;
        return count;
 }
```

Then tried adding it to the `ng-model` something like `"vm.add.something '+ vm.increment()'"`

I want all of form1 elements to have 1 added to the `ng-model="vm.add.something1"` and then when I copy the form it has 2 added to all the elements eg. `ng-model="vm.add.something2"`

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to add the increment, clicking something? BTW set the `ng-model` variable to `++` each time you want it:

```
 vm.counter = function () {
      vm.add.something1++;
 }
```

Comment: When the page loads I want it to be there then when I make copy of the  page I want to call it again